# ACL permissions set correctly but user still doesn't have access

Tags: permissions, users

I am trying to give access to a user named 'test' for a specific directory under `/var/log`, but not everything else under `/var/`.

I used the following commands:

```
sudo setfacl -R -m user:test:--- /var/
sudo setfacl -R -m user:test:rwx /var/log/test_dir/
```

`getfacl` shows that the permissions are set correctly:

```
# file: var/log/test_dir/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:test:rwx

# file: var
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:test:---
```

However, when trying to `ls` the contents of `test_dir` or `cat` a file existing inside `test_dir`, it still says

```
ls: cannot access '/var/log/test_dir': Permission denied
```

It seems like somehow the first command still overrides the second?